# Powershell variable displays correctly, but can't be used in mathematical operations?

Tags: powershell

The following mathematics needs to be done, and is very successfully executed when I set the values manually, such as `$a1 = 5, $a2 = 9` etc...

```
$a = [math]::sqrt([math]::pow(($a2-$a7),2)+([math]::pow(($b2+$b7),2)))
$b = [math]::sqrt([math]::pow(($a1-$a7),2)+([math]::pow(($b1+$b7),2)))
$c = [math]::sqrt([math]::pow(($a1-$a2),2)+([math]::pow(($b1-$b2),2)))
$div = 2*[math]::sqrt(([math]::pow($a,2))*([math]::pow($c,2)))
$div_ini = ([math]::pow($a,2))-([math]::pow($b,2))+([math]::pow($c,2))
([math]::acos($div_ini/$div))*180/[math]::pi
```

But when I try to set the variables in this way: `$a1 = Get-Content a1.txt -First 1` Then suddenly it does not work, and just returns NaN.

When I saw this, I checked if the variables even have the numbers set, so I wrote `$a1` and yes, the number was there, it's not missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get-Content returns a **string**, not a numeric value. Cast it to a decimal, e.g.

> $a1 = Get-Content [decimal]a1.txt - First 1

This might be viewed as a repeat of [a previous question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966938/how-can-i-convert-a-string-such-as-5-7303333333e02-to-a-decimal-type-in-powersh).